# Anyway to convert a plugin to become a shortcode?

Tags: plugins, shortcode

is there any (easy) way to convert an existing plugin to become shortcode instead? 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rax-top-social-media-share-with-counter/

I want to place it's output specifically in the layout and not below posts like plugin does automatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sure, but it will take a little bit of hacking.

I took a quick look at the plugin and what you want is in the function `rax_social_media_share_show_option()`. I would copy it and make a new function with just the part that builds up `$button_code`. That's from line 315 to 516.

Add a simple one-tag [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) that returns `$button_code` and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: ...and Marry your aunt. haha! +1